# regex to get string between one or two delimiters

Tags: java, regex

Given the following strings, with categories separated by a '+' (plus sign)

```
a1
a1+b1
a1+b2
a1+b1+c1
a2+b3
a2+b4
```

I want to extract all categories. This has to be done in multiple runs, one run per level. Given this example, it will take three runs:

**Run 1**

```
a1
a1
a1
a1
a2
a2
```

**Run 2**

```
b1
b2
b1
b3
b4
```

**Run 3**

```
c1
```

I already have some code, but since I have many more levels, I would like to make it more readable, so I can somehow indicate easily which level (hence how many plus signs before the category) I want to extract.

This is my current regex for level 3

```
^[^\+]*\+[^\+]*\+([^\+]*)\+?.*
```

FYI: this code is run with [Cellfie for Protégé](https://github.com/protegeproject/cellfie-plugin), which uses Java Regex Patterns

**Answer**

As a future reference, this is what I have made in [Cellfie](https://github.com/protegeproject/cellfie-plugin) with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42119123/1381490)

[image: extract multiple levels divided by delimiter]

I however sometimes still get only-whitespace-characters as results... anyway to exclude those?

Comment: Isn't it easier to split line on `+` character?

Comment: that would indeed be easier, but the program I am using cannot do that, and I do not want to bring other steps in the process.

Comment: You cant do simple `string.split("\\+")[level]`?

Comment: I can only use one regex per run...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original pattern was fine. I would just make it more readable like this:

- `^(?:[^+]*\+){2}([^+]*)` where `{2}` is the number of plus signs to skip.

Note that you don't need to escape the plus sign when it is inside of a character class.

Or, if you prefer `\w` as Edulynch suggested, then that would be:

- `^(?:\w*\+){2}(\w*)`

But I find that one to be less readable when encoded as a Java string, due to the extra backslashes.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Just one more small question: how can I avoid having whitespaces returned? apparantly sometimes " " (one space) is returned, and I want to exclude those

Comment: it can have whitespaces within one value, but if it's only whitespaces it should be excluded

Comment: This will trim leading whitespace from the string: `^(?:[^+]*\+){2}\s*([^+]*)`

Comment: ok, I thought so, then it is some bug in the Cellfie program; I will check. Thanks for your contribution to a large European clinical research project, CENTER-TBI ;-)

Comment: @intrixius I don't know much about Cellfie, but I'm guessing it might be because you need a match of width 1 or more. If that's the case, try this: `^(?:[^+]*\+){2}\s*+([^+]+)` it captures leading spaces with a possessive qualifier.

Comment: I have done some checks and it appears that "aa+bb" causes an empty result (= " ") for level 3 with `^(?:[^+]*\+){2}\s*+([^+]+)`

Comment: @intrixius in that case you are right: it must be a limitation of Cellfie. CENTER-TBI sounds like a great project. If they are hiring, check my developer profile. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This Should Work.

RegExp:

```
(\w+)(?:\+(\w+))?(?:\+(\w+))?
```

Input:

```
a1
a1+b1
a1+b2
a1+b1+c1
a2+b3
a2+b4
```

Output:

[image]

Java Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JAVAOCA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "(\\w+)(?:\\+(\\w+))?(?:\\+(\\w+))?";
        final String string = "a1\n"
                + "a1+b1\n"
                + "a1+b2\n"
                + "a1+b1+c1\n"
                + "a2+b3\n"
                + "a2+b4";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Group:

**$1**

```
a1
a1
a1
a1
a2
a2
```

**$2**

```
b1
b2
b1
b3
b4
```

**$3**

```
c1
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/qSz5WT/1

Comment: will have a look at it, looks promising... the regex101 site is also very helpful!

Comment: i've added groups (Run1 = $1, Run2 = $2 and Run3 = $3).

Comment: Why Pattern.MULTILINE ? You are using neither `^` nor `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution that you accepted from Patrick:

```
^(?:[^+]*\+){2}([^+]*)
```

(for identifying the third group of interest), to avoid the empty string matchings, you could try replacing the last `*` with `+`.

```
^(?:[^+]*\+){2}([^+]+)
```

This shouldn't match empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting each string with delimiter.

```
int max_level=0;
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> levels = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
for(int i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
   {
   items=inputs[i].split("\\+");
   for(int j=0;j<items.length;j++)
      {
      if(j>max_level)
         {
         max_level=j;
         ArrayList<String> strings=new ArrayList<>();
         levels.add(strings);
         }
      levels.get(j).add(items[j]);
      }
  }
```

Now levels.get(0) will give you the list of items in first level. The only regex used here is `\\+`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 3 **columns** and want to **match** every time **one of them** you simply need a **regex** that have **3** optional `\w+` and also **2** optional `\+`. That's it.

**result**
`/(\w+)?\+?(\w+)?\+?(\w+)?/`

**Then**
`$1` contains first column
`$2` contains second column
`$3` contains third column
[prove](https://regex101.com/r/nHZDO7/1)